# Extending an array to a specified length, alternating directions

Tags: beginner, array, go

I am working on golang and trying to understand to write good code not translated from another language, so I have written this program just for learning.

I want to perform operation on this array `[1,2,3,4]` with limit of `10`, so that i get this output `[1,2,3,4, 4,3,2,1, 1,2]`.

This function working correctly but I want to see suggestions for optimizations and improvements.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func arrayExm(array []int, limit int) []int {
    var res []int

    length := len(array)

    for i:=0; i < limit; i++ {

        if(i/length)%2 == 0{
            res = append(res,array[i%length])

        } else {
            res = append(res, array[length -i % length - 1])
        }
    }

    return res

}
func main() {
 fmt.Println(" Array with limit", arrayExm([]int{1,2,3,4},10))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This function working correctly but I want to see suggestions for
>   optimizations and improvements.

Your source code is undocumented. See [Godoc: documenting Go code](https://blog.golang.org/godoc-documenting-go-code).

By design, Go has a short, readable specification: [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec). As you write code, read useful parts of it in detail, for exanple, `make` (to make precise allocations), `append` (which may require multiple reallocations), `copy` (which has minimal bounds checking and may do block copies), and Index Expressions (which often require a bounds check), and so on.

Browse the [Go standard library](https://golang.org/pkg/) for useful packages. For example, the [`testing`](https://golang.org/pkg/testing/) package provides testing and benchmark facilities.

Read and apply the [Go Code Review Comments](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/CodeReviewComments).

Your algorithm takes an array element view of the problem. Consider other algorihms. For example, a repeating, alternating pattern of input and reverse input.

---

> I want to see other way.

That's an excellent idea. I usually try to come up with three different ways to do things, although I often settle for two. I use code reviews to ask other people for ideas.

Here's one other way. It's a little different and much more efficient than your way. It uses the Go standard library and code review conventions, and Go's test and benchmark facilities.

**`alternate.go`:**

```
package main

import "fmt"

// alternate returns a list of length n
// with alternating a and reverse a.
func alternate(a []int, n int) []int {
    b := make([]int, n)
    // copy a
    copy(b, a)
    // copy reverse a
    for i, j := len(a)-1, len(a); i >= 0 && j < len(b); i, j = i-1, j+1 {
        b[j] = a[i]
    }
    // copy repeating pattern
    for i := 2 * len(a); i < n; i *= 2 {
        copy(b[i:], b[:i])
    }
    return b
}

func main() {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    for i := 0; i < 4*len(a)+2; i++ {
        fmt.Println(alternate(a, i), i)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go run alternate.go
[] 0
[1] 1
[1 2] 2
[1 2 3] 3
[1 2 3 4] 4
[1 2 3 4 4] 5
[1 2 3 4 4 3] 6
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2] 7
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1] 8
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1] 9
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2] 10
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3] 11
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4] 12
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4] 13
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 3] 14
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 3 2] 15
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1] 16
[1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1 2 3 4 4 3 2 1 1] 17
$
```

**`alternate_test.go`:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "testing"
)

func TestAlternate(t *testing.T) {
    a := []int{1, 2, 3, 4}
    n := 10
    got := fmt.Sprint(alternate(a, n))
    want := fmt.Sprint([]int{1, 2, 3, 4, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1, 2})
    if want != got {
        t.Errorf("want: %v got: %v", want, got)
    }
}

func BenchmarkAlternate(b *testing.B) {
    a := make([]int, 42)
    for i := range a {
        a[i] = i
    }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        alternate(a, 1024)
    }
}

func arrayExm(array []int, limit int) []int {
    var res []int
    length := len(array)
    for i := 0; i < limit; i++ {
        if (i/length)%2 == 0 {
            res = append(res, array[i%length])
        } else {
            res = append(res, array[length-i%length-1])
        }
    }
    return res
}

func BenchmarkArrayExm(b *testing.B) {
    a := make([]int, 42)
    for i := range a {
        a[i] = i
    }
    b.ReportAllocs()
    b.ResetTimer()
    for i := 0; i < b.N; i++ {
        arrayExm(a, 1024)
    }
}
```

Output:

```
$ go test -v -bench=. alternate.go alternate_test.go
=== RUN   TestAlternate
--- PASS: TestAlternate (0.00s)
goos: linux
goarch: amd64
BenchmarkAlternate-4    500000    2576 ns/op    8192 B/op    1 allocs/op
BenchmarkArrayExm-4      50000   25783 ns/op   16376 B/op   11 allocs/op
PASS
ok      command-line-arguments  4.388s
$
```

Comment: Thank you So much Peter for this i am also figure out other possible ways